# How to get parameter value for date/time column from empty MaskedTextBox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having a problem adding a parameter of date/time type to my insert statement. For textual data you can leave the textbox empty and the record will be added but with date/time data I can't. I get the following error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

I want my date/time `MaskedTextBox` (`__/__/____`) to be added even if it is empty. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub btnBookADD_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBookADD.Click
    Dim sqlinsert As String = "INSERT INTO tblBookIssue([Accession Number],[Book Title],[Student Name],[Years],[Section],[Date Issue],[Date to be Return],[Date Returned])  VALUES ('" & txtBookAccessNumber.Text & "' , '" & txtBookBookTitle.Text & "' , '" & txtBookStudentName.Text & "' , '" & txtBookYears.Text & "' , '" & txtBookSection.Text & "' , '" & txtBookDateIssue.Text & "' , '" & txtBookDatetobeReturn.Text & "' , '" & txtBookDateReturned.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Accession_Number", txtBookAccessNumber.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Book_Title", txtBookBookTitle.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Student_Name", txtBookStudentName.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Years", txtBookYears.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Section", txtBookSection.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Date_Issue", txtBookDateIssue.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Date_to_be_Return", txtBookDatetobeReturn.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Date_Returned", txtBookDateReturned.Text))

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("One Record Added")
    RefreshDataGridview3()
End Sub
```

Comment: Which control is your `MaskedTextBox`? Also, is that column nullable in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing the `.Text` properties of the textboxes directly into the database, this doesn't work. The `.Text` properties are `String`s (i.e. simple text) and not typed as `DateTime` instances. Do the conversion first, then it will work.

Do this for each date parameter:

```
Dim bookIssueDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact( txtBookDateIssue.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
cmd.Parameters.Add( New OleDbParameter("@Date_Issue", bookIssueDate ) )
```

Note that this code will crash/fail if a user enters an invalid date, e.g. "64/48/9999", I suggest using `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`, but implementing that is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thnk u sir for fast reply but could u translate ur code into vb.net 2008 bcoz its my current version. thnk u sir!

Comment: You might also consider using a `DateTimePicker` control instead.